# pr_entryid is not unique for recipients (Outlook / C++ / MAPI)

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi

If I create two meetings both having the same invitee's email address, both Recipient objects in their respective AppointmentItem objects get the same PR_ENTRYID! At the same time, their instance keys are different. However, I have to reference items by their PR_ENTRYID as this seems to be the only way to pass ids between COM automation and MAPI (COM does not provide instance key to MAPI).

How can I overcome this? I'm using Outlook 2010 32-bit.

PR_ENTRYIDs of two Recipient items (equal):

00000000FE42AA0A18C71A10E8850B651C24000003000000040000000000000018000000000000001E7FDF4152B0E944BA66DFBF2C6A6416E4F52000487F22

00000000FE42AA0A18C71A10E8850B651C24000003000000040000000000000018000000000000001E7FDF4152B0E944BA66DFBF2C6A6416E4F52000487F22

Instance keys (not equal):

0000D79F

0000D7B0

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is still the same as at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/outlookdev/thread/87a62535-8e7c-4fc2-bcf8-425aa9388dda

Why do you expect the recipient entry ids to be different? It is the same recipient (name/address/address type), hence the entry id is the same.

What exactly are you trying to do and why?